# How to bind an List<IFormFile> property dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

My issue is very similar to my previous post:

[How to bind a property to a dynamic list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462373/how-to-bind-a-property-to-a-dynamic-list-of-objects)

However I am trying to do the same thing that solved this problem in my previous post with a more complex control, an input file selector. Due to this, my question is very similar, however in this case I am guessing the fix is slightly different since the previous solution did not work. Anyhow here goes:

I am using the .net core 2.2 framework and am having trouble finding out how I can bind a list of IFormFile to a razor page. On the razor page I have a button to add a new file input to the screen. This button executes a jquery click event that alters the html to add a new input button of type file without refreshing the page. What I am looking to do with this, is that when I add a new button it binds the selected file to the List object. I can then process this list of items when I post the form.

My Razor Page cs looks something like this:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    #region Variables

    private readonly MyContext _myContext;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [BindProperty]
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public CreateModel(MyContext myContext)
    {
        _myContext = myContext;            
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        #region Create instance of a FormFile for testing purposes

        FormFile file;
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("/test.txt"))
        {
            file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, stream.Name, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "text/css",
            };
        }

        Files.Add(file);

        #endregion

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

The Razor Page cshtml looks something like this:

```
...
<div id="file-container">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="myfile">
            <label class="control-label">Upload file</label>
            <input asp-for="Files[i]" type="file" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div class="item-add">
    <a id="add-file" class="link-button"><img class="add-file" src="@Url.Content("~/images/ic_add.png")" />Add File</a>
</div>
```

and finally here is my jquery code:

```
$("#add-file").click(function () {
    var nextId = $(".file").length;

    var rowHtml = '<div class="file">' +
        '<label class="control-label">Upload file</label>' +
        '<input id="Files_' + nextId + '_" name="Files[' + nextId + ']" type="file" />' +
        '</div>';

    $("#file-container").append(rowHtml);
});
```

Finally, when I post the form that contains this code, I want to be able to access the values input into the dynamically created html from my binded property.

*If there is anything that is not understood please let me know and I will try clarifying.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Apparently when you work with input files it appears that you don't use the [i] part as in normal cases. Below is the code that changed:

```
<div id="file-container">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="myfile">
            <label class="control-label">Upload file</label>
            <input asp-for="Files" type="file" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and in jquery:

```
$("#add-file").click(function () {
    var nextId = $(".file").length;

    var rowHtml = '<div class="file">' +
        '<label class="control-label">Upload file</label>' +
        '<input id="Files" name="Files" type="file" />' +
        '</div>';

    $("#file-container").append(rowHtml);
});
```